# How do you specify seperate sets of y axis limits for each sector of a circlize plot?

Tags: r, plot, circlize

I have three sets of data that I want to plot using Circlize. Set's "a" and "b" contain positive and negative values, set "c" contains only positive values. I want to plot using a consistent y axis for "a" and "b" and different one for "c". Unfortunately, I can't find a way of doing this.

The code i'm using is below, I seem to only be able to have unique y axis for each or  a fixed y axis for all (if you uncomment "ylim..." in the code).

I've tried a few things, trying to loop through using the `circos.lines()` function instead but this didn't solve it.

`circos.info()` shows separate y axis limits so i think it should be possible.

Thanks in advance.

```
library("circlize")
library("reshape")


#--- Data ---#

a <- sort(rnorm(100,0,10))
b <- sort(rnorm(100,0,5))
c <- abs(rnorm(100,0,200))

data <- cbind("a" = a, "b" = b, "c" = c)
data_melt <- melt(data)


#--- Plotting ---#

circos.initialize(      factors = data_melt$X2, 
                        x = data_melt$X1, 
                        sector.width = 1
                        )   

circos.trackPlotRegion( factors = data_melt$X2, 
                        y = data_melt$value, 
#                       ylim = range(data_melt$value),
                        force.ylim = FALSE, 
                        panel.fun = function(x, y) { circos.axis( ) }
                        )

circos.trackLines(      data_melt$X2, 
                        data_melt$X1, 
                        data_melt$value, 
                        type = "h",
                        col = "grey",
                        lwd = 3, 
                        baseline = 0)`

circos.info(sector.index = NULL, track.index = 1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ylim` can be matrix in which each row corresponds to the y-range in each sector.

```
set.seed(123)
a <- sort(rnorm(100,0,10))
b <- sort(rnorm(100,0,1))
c <- abs(rnorm(100,0,200))

data <- cbind("a" = a, "b" = b, "c" = c)
data_melt <- melt(data)


#--- Plotting ---#
r_ab = range(data_melt[data_melt$X2 != "c", "value"])
r_c = range(data_melt[data_melt$X2 == "c", "value"])

circos.par(gap.degree = 5)
circos.initialize(      factors = data_melt$X2, 
                        x = data_melt$X1, 
                        sector.width = 1
                        )   

ylim = rbind(r_ab, r_ab, r_c)
circos.trackPlotRegion( factors = data_melt$X2, 
                        x = data_melt$X1,
                        y = data_melt$value, 
                        ylim = ylim,
                        force.ylim = F, 
                        panel.fun = function(x, y) { 
                            circos.lines(x, y, type = "h", col = "grey", lwd =3, baseline = 0)
                            circos.axis(labels.cex = 0.6) 
                            circos.yaxis(labels.cex = 0.6)
                        }
                       )
circos.clear()
```

I also moved the code from `circos.trackLines()` to `panel.fun()` (because I think `panel.fun()` is more flexible to add multiple layers of graphics).

Also I added `circos.yaxis()` because y-axis has different ranges in sectors, it is important to explicitly show the y-ranges.

[image]

Comment: Hi Zuguang, thank you for your answer. Do you happen to know how to generalise this for when "a", "b" and "c" contain different numbers of observations? I run up against the error: "Error in circos.lines(x, y, type = "h", col = "grey", lwd = 3, baseline = 0) :   Length of x and y differ.". I've tried to modify using sector.index but have not been able to successfully generalise it.

Comment: The number of observations in each category should not affect the plot. Can you check whether `data_melt$X1` and `data_melt$value` have the same length? Or can you check other part of your code? It works fine with unequal number of observation on my side.

Comment: Apologies, I had mis-specified something in the code i'm writing. It works now. Thanks again and thanks for the package.